# Using Bluemix Mobile Services dashboard and foundation download code gives error

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am using the mobile services dashboard and trying to deploy a mobile app to a Mobile Foundation Server. After I build my application using mobile app builder I select "Get Code". One of my options is to "Deploy to Foundation", but when I select it I can't get it to deploy to a V8 server and if I select Download code from that same pop up I get a 404 error.

In my foundation settings I am putting "mobilefoundation-XX-XX-server.mybluemix.net/mfpconsole/" as the publish location.  When I push the Deploy button it seems to do something (spinner over Deploy Button spins twice), but nothing is deployed. I have been able to get this to work when I deploy a mobile app to a V7.1 MFP Server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the wrong publish location. Here are how my settings looked when I deployed to a V8 MFP Server successfully:

[image: mfp]

Comment: Thanks I also realized the problem in my publish location. I had tried it several ways and now I narrowed the problem to deploying to both OSes at the same time.  If I  "get the Code" for both Android and iOS at the same time and then try to deploy to MFF. they won't both deploy. So if I deploy iOS first and then deploy Android from that same get code screeen. It will look like it is deploying, with the spinner going, but it doesn't show up in the console as an app.  I guess it must have the same identifier in MFF and when the second one deploys it can't because it is already there for iOS.